# Column name included in each list/array item (LINQ CSV reader)

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I am using this CSV reader in attempt to print out Name, lastname and SSN from my CSV file:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var query = File.ReadLines(@"C:\CSV\ToAdd.csv")
                        .SelectMany(line => line.Split(';'))
                        .Where(csvLine => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(csvLine))
                        .Select(csvLine => new { data = csvLine.Split(',') })
                        .Select(s => new
                        {
                            Name = s.data[0],
                            Lastname = s.data[1],
                            SSN = s.data[2]
                        });

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

So far I have had a bit of success, but the problem is it keeps printing out the name of the column as well:

```
{ Name = Hej, Lastname = Hoj, SSN= 950505-1432 }
{ Name = Huj, Lastname = Hij, SSN= 940304-1332 }
```

which part of the code is making it so it gets printed out like that instead of printing out only the records?

Comment: I recommend updating the question+title to better reflect the problem - When printing this linq generated anonymous type object it isn't in the format you expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print it this way:

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

It uses the `ToString()` implemented by .Net for anonymous types generated by the compiler. It's implementation is to print the data in that format of property name + value.

When you want to do instead is give a specific format for when printing:

1. Using String Interpolation of C# 6 (which is just syntactic sugar
   for `string.Format`) you can do it like this:

   ```
   foreach (var item in query)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} {item.Lastname}, {item.SSN}");
   }
   ```
2. Using another overload of the `Console.WriteLine`:

   ```
   foreach (var item in data)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}, {2}",item.Name, item.Lastname, item.SSN);
   }
   ```

   3.Or if you project to a defined type and not an anonymous type you can override the `ToString` of the object and then your code from the question will work